# How exactly works this REST method that handle a POST request in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, annotations

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have some doubt related to an exercise on **RESTful webapp* in Spring MVC.

So, in the example, I have the following method that create a new **Account** object

```
/**
 * Creates a new Account, setting its URL as the Location header on the
 * response.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public HttpEntity<String> createAccount(@RequestBody Account newAccount,
        @Value("#{request.requestURL}") StringBuffer url) {
    Account account = accountManager.save(newAccount);

    return entityWithLocation(url, account.getEntityId());
}
```

I know that:

1. **@RequestMapping** annotation, in this case, specify that this method handle **POST** HttpRequest towards the **/accounts** resource. I know that it use the **POST** request because according to the REST style the POST "verbs" means that a new resource have to be created.
2. I think that this annotation:

   ```
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
   ```

   means that when the method correctly end (when the **HttpResponse** is send to the client) it put the **201** (**CREATED**) into the HttpResponse status field. So it specify that the creation of the new object is gone ok. Is it true or am I missing something?
3. The first parameter of the method is:

   ```
   @RequestBody Account newAccount
   ```

   Reading the documentation it seems to me that this parameter is bounded to the body of the web request. The body of the request is passed through an HttpMessageConverter to resolve the method argument depending on the content type of the request.

   So, what exactly means? I think that it means that into the **body** of my HttpRequest I have my Account object in JSON format and that it is used Jackson to convert it into a classic **Account** Java object. Is it right or am I missing something?
4. The second parameter of the method is:

   @Value("#{request.requestURL}") StringBuffer url

   What exactly means?
5. Then the method save the obtained object on the database.
6. Finally it return:

   ```
   return entityWithLocation(url, account.getEntityId());
   ```

   but what exactly means? what is returning? and where? the result is not into the HttpResponse?

**EDIT 1:**

The **entityWithLocation()** method is definied in the same class of the previous method and this is its code:

```
private HttpEntity<String> entityWithLocation(StringBuffer url,
        Object resourceId) {
    // Configure and return an HttpEntity object - it will be used to build
    // the HttpServletResponse
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(getLocationForChildResource(url, resourceId));
    return new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
}
```

Comment: Where is entityWithLocation method defined? can you post it's implementation?

Comment: @TyrionLannister edited my original post adding the required information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is my understanding on your question.

> 3. > @RequestBody Account newAccount

Your understanding is correct,regarding this point.

> 4. @Value("#{request.requestURL}") StringBuffer url

It is equivalent to request.getRequestURL(); See [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL())

> 5. entityWithLocation(url, account.getEntityId())

As per code inside this method.
 It returns `HttpEntity` Object,which represent http request or response entity(`which includes headers and body`),in your case it is `response`.
 Inside the method,you have added the `location` of `resource(account)` created.